# Duplicated elements in documents using class inheritance

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I'm using C#'s MongDB Driver 2.7.2 (server 4.0.5) with my application and trying to insert this model:

```
abstract class ModelBase
{
    public virtual int Duration { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}

class MongoModel : ModelBase
{

   [BsonElement("_id")]
   public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

   [BsonElement("duration")]
   public override int Duration { get; set; }

   [BsonElement("end_date")]
   public override DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

   [BsonElement("start_date")]
   public override DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

I use this class inheritance because I want to be able to create a MongoBase (MongoDB), DynamoBase (AWS), etc

But, when is inserted, the next document is shown (with duplicated elements):

```
class MongoDBDataProvider : DataProvider
{
    private MongoClient _client;
    public MongoDBDataProvider(string endpoint) : base(endpoint)
    {
        _connectionString = $"mongodb://{_endpoint}";
        _client = new MongoClient(_connectionString);
    }


    public override async Task Insert(ModelBase src)
    {
        var coll = GetCollection();
        await coll.InsertOneAsync((MongoModel)src);
    }

    private IMongoCollection<MongoModel> GetCollection()
    {
        IMongoDatabase db = _client.GetDatabase("db");
        return db.GetCollection<MongoModel>("coll");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
_id:5c4123116b2940340551785f
Duration:10
EndDate:2020-02-02 05:02:00.000
StartDate:2020-02-02 05:02:00.000
duration:10
end_date:2020-02-02 05:02:00.000
start_date:2020-02-02 05:02:00.000
```

Why is this happening? Any hint? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

using BsonIgnore attribute to ignore property

```
public interface ModelBase
{
    int Duration { get; set; }
    DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that fix my problem. But, this isn't against Open Close? I don't want to ModelBase known nothing about the other implementations. If I need to add another databases sources, I will need to modify this class again with the attributes that the new database driver require.

Comment: In this case , you probably try interface ModelBase.